# Azure Cloud Publish Unable to import module Caching. No manifest was found error in Service Definition

Tags: visual-studio, caching, azure-cloud-services

I am getting this error when i add caching module to ServiceDefitinition.csdef.
I already add below settings to ServiceDefinition and ServiceConfiguration

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ConfigStoreConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.NamedCaches" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.DiagnosticLevel" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.CacheSizePercentage" />
```

I tried to repair Visual Studio to but didn't make any difference.
When i remove the caching module i can publish to my cloudapp, but my website needs this caching module to properly working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, problem was Azure SDK version (i think). When i tried to publish from my old computer (with exact codes) it published successfully.